# Create new table using implode

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, implode

I have a huge table from one mysql db, I want to create a new table in different mysql db and copy 3 columns from the huge one. To do that, I wrote the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM huge_table", $hugeDB);
    $count = mysql_result($result, 0);
    $iterations=ceil($count/500);    

    for($i=1; $i<=$iterations; $i++)
    {
        $start = ($i-1)*500;
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT col1, col3, col6 FROM huge_table LIMIT $i, 500", $hugeDB);
        $results = array();
        $j = 0;
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $result[$j]= '('.$result['col1'].', '.$result['col3'].', '.$result['col6'].')';
            $j++;
        }
        print_r($results);
        $a = mysql_query("INSERT INTO less_huge_table (col1, col3, col6) VALUES ".implode(',', $results), $localDB);
        if(!$a) die(mysql_error()."\n");
    }
```

But then the output is:

```
Unknown column 'BTFG' in 'field list'
```

Where BTFG is the array's first element's item:

```
(2007-01-03, BTFG, 23.0481)
```

I think I'm making a little mistake but I couldn't catch.

How should I solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is  `$result` not `$resullts`. You declared array with `$results` then assigned values in `$result` and in insert you are using `$results` which is blank.

it should be

```
  while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $results[$j]= '("'.$result['col1'].'", "'.$result['col3'].'", "'.$result['col6'].'")';
   ....
   }
```

BTW what is `$j++`  not used anywhere else.

**EDIT:**

quote char and string values properly:

```
('2007-01-03', 'BTFG', 23.0481)
```

change here :

```
 $results[$j]= '("'.$result['col1'].'", "'.$result['col3'].'", "'.$result['col6'].'")';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a [single query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) with MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO less_huge_table (col1, col3, col6)
   SELECT col1, col3, col6
   FROM huge_table
```

This removes the need to round-trip the values through a script. As well, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Even though you've gotten this data from the database directly, it can STILL contain sql metacharacters which you then blindly stuff back into another query. Yes, it is **ENTIRELY** possible to inject yourself.

Comment: But while I'm running this query which connection should be active ? For example if localDB connection active, then I won't be able to reach the data in huge_table.

Comment: this query won't lock the tables unless you create the locks explicitly.

Comment: But which DB should I connect ? If I make a connection to localDB, when I say FROM huge_table, it says Table huge_table doesn't exists

Comment: You can specify databases in the query to do cross-db queries: `INSERT INTO db1.less_huge ... SELECT ... FROM otherdb.huge_table...`

Comment: Maybe I don't know or I do not explain the situation well, for hugeDB I'm connecting different address with different username and password, for localDB I have also different address and login information. So these databases are not stored in the same place. Can I stil do that ?

Comment: Ah. That is a different matter. Are both databases MySQL? You can use a 'federated' table type to make the remote DB appear local, then still use the select ... into

Answer (score 1):

It might just be easier and faster to do this entirely with a MySQL statement and you don't have to use two connections assuming your databases are on the same server and credentials are the same or authorized.

For example:-

```
mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO less_huge_table (col1, col3, col6) SELECT col1, col3, col6 FROM huge_table LIMIT $i, 500', $hugeDB );
```

If you really need the data then across to a local database on a different server, just query the system again for your less_huge_table only.  This prevents you from having to get your information into PHP and ensure you are escaping and passing it back to the new insert statement properly, MySQL will handle it for you from table to table.

However, based on your code above it's possible there is non-escaped data coming from the huge table that's breaking your query.  The "Array()" would be from your print_r command and the error from the next insert error.  So you can always just print your SQL statement, instead of executing it and review it directly.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'm new here. I'll remember to format next time.